# are these file paths safe?

Tags: virus, malware, avg-antivirus

I ran an AVG scan on my macbook and it quarantined the following path(s), are they safe ?

1. /private/var/db/uuidtext/27/5C90F7E4A93732B3C1B576AF6DA7D5
2. /private/var/db/uuidtext/CE/091E3F4BEB3FA1BB3B9B04E33EA54D
3. /private/var/db/uuidtext/8B/BB1EDDB3363F1BBA0C9C25D1A3DD42
4. /Users/mgj/Library/Application Support/com.QuickLookSearches/QuickLookSearches
5. /Users/mgj/Library/Application Support/amc/helperamc.app/Contents/Resources/infs
6. /Users/mgj/Library/Application Support/amc/helperamc.app/Contents/Resources/rlistupdater.app/Contents/MacOS/rlistupdater
7. /Users/mgj/Library/Application Support/amc/helperamc.app/Contents/MacOS/helperamc

thank you for any help

Comment: what is the reason for that "quarantined"?

Comment: I ran an AVG scan on my computer.

Answer (score 1):

Those are not "safe" file paths.

For example the path:
/Users/mgj/Library/Application Support/amc/helperamc.app

... refers to "Advanced Mac Cleaner" which is a "fake utility" program which promises to "clean" or make your computer "faster" while doing quite the opposite.

So AVG is right to quarantine the "helperamc".

You can read more about the scam utility from the Apple forums:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7135825?tstart=0

Or just by googling "Advanced Mac Cleaner".